# using ng-sidebar as a sidenav

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been able to create the sidebar with [ng-sidebar](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar) and the help of [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-sidebar?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) and [this](https://echeung.me/ng-sidebar/) sample. The issue i am having is i have no idea how to use a routerlink with this library on a single page application. The ng-sidebar-content is where the main page should be rendered but i can't display a different component. `

```
<!-- A sidebar -->
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" position="left" mode="push" closeOnClickOutside="true">
  <ul>
    <button (click)="_toggleOpened()" class="mt-2">Toggle sidebar</button>
    <li [routerLink]="['/main']">Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</ng-sidebar>

<!-- Page content -->
<div ng-sidebar-content>
  <app-home></app-home>

</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing is explained here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Import `RouterModule`, define your routes in `app.module.ts`.

And use `router-outlet` like this:

```
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" position="left" mode="push" closeOnClickOutside="true">
  <ul>
    <button (click)="_toggleOpened()" class="mt-2">Toggle sidebar</button>
    <li [routerLink]="['/main']">Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</ng-sidebar>

<!-- Page content -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```